# Keep get in a submitted form

Tags: php

Ok so I have a redirect function for my login. Heres some code:

```
if ($sukces) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

    if($_POST['location'] != '') {
        header('Refresh: 1;url='.$_POST['location'].'');
    echo message('You have logged in.<br>Press <a href="'.$_POST['location'].'">here</a> if you are not returned automatically.');
    return false;
    } else {
        header("Location: /home");
    }

} else {
    // login failed
    exit();
}

if($_POST['location'] != '') {
    header('Refresh: 1;url='.$_POST['location'].'');
} else {
    header("Location: /account");
}


<form action="?page=login" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?=isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) ? htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['redirect']) : ''?>">


E.g:
http://localhost/?page=login&redirect=%2Fforum%2F%3Faction%3Dpost%26boardid%3D1
```

The problem is if you enter the wrong login credentials the value of location input field will become empty. But if you enter the wrong and then enter the right you wont be redirected. Why is that? How do I keep the redirect url?

Comment: you are not doing anything apart from an exit(); in the else case (login field). I think you need to make changes there.

Comment: try changing `exit()` to `echo "login failed"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this instead:

```
<form action="?page=login<?=isset($_GET['redirect']) ? '&redirect='.urlencode($_GET['redirect']) : ''?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

The second time you reach this page, it's essentially a complete reload, with PHP doing its whole form processing again. This time, though, there's no 'redirect' parameter in the request when it's making the form. There is, however, a 'location' parameter, originating from your hidden form input. I'd say you have two good options:

- Change either 'location' or 'redirect' so you're always using the same parameter name
- Have the PHP code near the bottom decide to use either 'location', or if that's not available, 'redirect'.

Answer (score 0):

You inject the 'redirect' back into your form as a hidden field. That is a good start. But you change its name to 'location'. Set the hidden field's name to 'redirect' and it will be resubmitted properly.  I believe this was your initial intention.